# Customize password request string

Tags: terminal, password, appearance

I'd like to know if there's a way to customize the sudo password request.

The default string is:

```
[sudo] password for USER:
```

Is there a way to change that to some other custom string, like:

```
Insert sudo password:
```

?

I want to clear this: I'm *not* asking how to change the password. I'm asking how to edit the terminal string that appears in the terminal when the system asks for the user password.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Have a look at the `passprompt` option in the `SUDOERS OPTIONS` section of `man sudoers`

Comment: Thank you. I found the solution by using an alias. :)

Comment: It may not matter, but the proposed password prompt is misleading. There is no such thing as a "sudo password". Why would you want to obfuscate the prompt?

Comment: That was just an example. :)
I wanted to know how to change it for the main sake of (my personal) knowledge. But I must admit that I changed it to a simple padlock now: . I might play with that a bit. All in all, it's something that I'm doing in my personal computer that I only use. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this like in the following example:

```bsh
sudo -p 'Insert sudo password: ' echo "Hello World!"
```

Comment: Thank you! I got what I was looking for by adding an alias like "alias sudo='sudo --prompt="Enter password: "' to my .bashrc file. :)